Inconsistent Results with Google Groups List People API : Missing Groups for Some Users
I'm using the Google Groups List API with the JavaScript SDK to fetch groups for authenticated users. It generally works well, but for some users, it doesn't fetch all their groups. For instance, if a user has 8-9 groups, the initial API call might only return 1 group. After a few hours, subsequent API calls might return 1-2 additional groups, but it's still not fetching all of them. Eventually, it might show 2-4 groups, but it never retrieves the complete list. What could be causing this inconsistent behavior for some users, and how can I ensure that all groups are fetched reliably?
Additionally, the API response is saved in the database for verification purposes to ensure it works well. Using the Google API response, I identified this problem.
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/list
below is code for node js GroupList API call.
 const res = await service.contactGroups.list({
      pageSize: 1000,
      syncToken,
      pageToken: nextPageToken,
    });

